# Fetching multiple pages in Django rest framework pagination

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

i set pagination in my django rest framework

settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 4,
}
```

JSON i get:

```
{
"count": 10,
"next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list?page=2",
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "name": "lorem ipsum1",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/2.jpg",
        "description": "lorem ipsum5"
    },
    {
        "name": "lorem2",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/1.jpg",
        "description": "lorem ipsum4"
    },
    {
        "name": "lorem ipsum3",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/3_miVerQW.jpg",
        "description": "lorem ipsum3"
    },
    {
        "name": "lorem ipsum4",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/4.jpg",
        "description": "lorem ipsum2"
    }
]
}
```

when i make http request, for example, http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list?page=1 i get the content only of page 1 (json above). is it possible to get content of several pages (for example content of pages 1 - 3) with one http request (maybe something like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list?page=1-3) ?

Comment: I don't _think_ so. Isn't that the whole point of pagination? Prevent clients from overwhelming the service?

Comment: I would increase the page size to match your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fetch multiple pages, but you can make the *size* of a page configurable. See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class MyPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
```

Then set this `MyPageNumberPagination` class in the configuration as `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS`, or as a `pagination_class` for a specific view.

Then you can request `/api/list?page=1&page_size=12` to fetch 12 items at a time, the same effect as fetching 3 pages at once.